# How to insert multiple data into one column

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to insert the data student name 'Dhiya' and 'Siti' and $checkbox into the database. I recall the data first from table student_course in the database. I checked Presence for both name. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<?php
include ('system2.php');
include('connect_database.php');
$course = $_POST['course'];
$batch = $_POST['batch'];
$group = $_POST['group'];
$student_name = $_POST['Student_Name'];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$query_view1 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct Student_Name FROM student_course where batch='12/01'");
$query_view2 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct Student_Name FROM student_course where batch='12/02'");

echo "<form action ='system23.php' method = 'post'>";
echo "<table border = '1' align='center'>";
echo "<tr>
    <th><font color=#555555>Name</font> </th>
    <th><font color=green>Presence</font> </th>
    <th><font color=red>Absence</font> </th>
    <th><font color=#FFCC00>Permission</font> </th>
    <th><font color=purple>Late</font> </th>
 </tr>";

if ($batch=='12/01')
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_view1) )
    {
        echo "<tr>";?>
        <td><input type="text" name="stuname" value="<?php echo $row['Student_Name']?>"/></td>
        <?php
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='P'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='A'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='PR'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='L'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
else if ($batch=='12/02')
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_view2) )
    {
        echo "<tr>";?>
        <td><input type="text" name="stuname" value="<?php echo $row['Student_Name']?>"/></td>
        <?php
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='P'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='A'/></td>";  
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='PR'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='L'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='6' align='center'><input name='submit' type='submit' value='GO' /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>"; 
?>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Then i tried to insert the data into the database. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<div class="container">
<?php
include ('system22.php');
include('connect_database.php');
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$query_view1 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct Student_Name FROM student_course where batch='12/02'");
$query_view2 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct Student_Name FROM student_course where batch='12/02'");
$student_name = $_POST['stuname'];
$batch= $_POST['batch'];
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO result2 VALUES ('$student_name', '$checkbox')");
echo "Success";
?>
</div>
</html>
```

But when i check the database, it only put 'Siti'. I don't know what other methods to use

Since  i can't post the image, i will try to make it as clear as possible

The table of student_course

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Siti</td>
            <td>P</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

For table result2 structure.

**Field**: 'Name' and '1'
**Type**: both varchar(99).
No primary and foreigh key.

Comment: can you show your table's structure?

Comment: since i can't post images yet, i made a html code for it and i have shown it already. The table of student_course

Comment: no, `result2` table structure

Comment: ok i have added the structure

Answer (score 1):

If you're inserting everything into one column only you need quotation marks around the whole string and not the two variables.

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO result2 VALUES ('$student_name, $checkbox')");
```

should work

Or you could simply add both variables to a new one like:

```
$insert = $student_name.", ".$checkbox;
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO result2 VALUES ('$insert')");
```

but the best option of them all is to switch to `PDO` for instance and prepare the statement to avoid `SQL` injection once and for all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement for weather or not the box was checked, for example.

```
if (!isset($_POST['checkboxname'])) {
    // checkbox was not checked
} else {
    // checkbox was checked
}
```

Comment: it's not necessary if you comply the order of fields in `VALUES()`

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer since that would not have worked.